# Selenium Python - select from autosuggest dropdown

Tags: python, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to select the first value of the drop down from the autosuggested list when I use sendkey with a value of 'ada' into the "Enter Company" field on the following page. http://www.moneycontrol.com/stocks/histstock.php

```
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="mycomp"]""")
inputElement.send_keys('ada')   
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="suggest"]/ul/li[1]""")
```

This doesn't seem to do the trick.

Please help.

Regards,

babsdoc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wait until required option appears in `DOM`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.find_element_by_id("mycomp").send_keys('ada')
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="suggest"]/ul/li[1]'))).click()
```

Comment: That worked like a charm Andersson. Thank you for your help, sincerely appreciated.