# python selenium autocomplete search issue

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to fill up an autocomplete zipcode / town form. Even if you input the whole zipcode / town in once you still must validate the autocomplete search (just under the input).I do not put the whole error messages for each attempt otherwise my post would be too long (I put a number for each attempt and --> to show the corresponding result).

the input:

```
ville = 31000 Toulouse
geo = driver.find_element_by_id("location_p")  
geo.send_keys(ville)
```

from here starts the issue: 
Here is the line making pbs:

```
<li data-region="16" data-dpt-code="31" class="selected">
<span class="city" title="Toulouse">Toulouse</span>&nbsp;
<span class="zipcode">31000</span>
</li>
```

1.

```
validate = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@class='selected'][contains(.,'data-dpt-code')]")
validate.click()
```

--> unable to locate element

2.

```
validate = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("li.selected") 
validate.click()
```

--> `<exception str() failed>`

but

```
validate = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("li.selected")
assertTrue(validate_is_displayed() and validate_is_enabled())
validate.click()
```

-> unable to locate element

3.
from this : [How to handle autocomplete list in webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423947/how-to-handle-autocomplete-list-in-webdriver), I tried:

```
geo.send_keys(Keys.TAB) 
geo.send_keys(Keys.TAB) 
geo.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
```

-> no error, but the zipcode / town is not validated

4.from [Selenium Python - select from autosuggest dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45018802/selenium-python-select-from-autosuggest-dropdown), tried

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

 wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@class='selected']/span[@class='city][contains(.,'Toulouse')]"
```

-> idem as 3

5.from [Selenium in Python How use a If - else code if an element is not present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39147245/selenium-in-python-how-use-a-if-else-code-if-an-element-is-not-present), I tried:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="selected"][contains(.,"data-dpt-code")]')
valid = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@class="city"][contains(.,"Toulouse")]')
if valid.is_displayed():
elem.click()
```

-> `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Element is not clickable at point (309.5, 9.75). Other element would receive the click: <section class="content-center clearfix"></section>`

I need your help folks!! Thanx in advance

Comment: Did you try `send_keys(Keys.RETURN)` to confirm auto-suggestion?

Comment: `<li data-region="16" data-dpt-code="31" ...` looks dynamic. Update the question with more of the outerHTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally had to work with chrome and chromedriver:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 
10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".location-list > 
li:nth-child(1)"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

From this error it looks like element is not located on the screen:

`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Element is not clickable at point (309.5, 9.75). Other element would receive the click: <section class="content-center clearfix"></section>`

Did you try to use Action chains and move to that element before you click ?

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(your_element).click().perform()
```

Comment: @Andersson - does not change anything.

Comment: @cieunteung - does not change anything

Comment: I tried this way: 
`mouse = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)`</br>
`element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="selected"][contains(.,"data-dpt-code")]')`  </br>
`mouse.move_to_element(element).perform()`  </br>
 but this does not solve the problem. 
Now, I can see that there is an outer square just above the square I was trying to click in. I guess this outer square is the one to work on. I will get back to you just to let you know. Many thanx guys.

Answer (score 0):

using WebdriverWait try clicking the `li` element

```
wait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//li[@class="selected" and contains(., "Toulouse")]'))
).click()
```

also try with different condition like `presence_of_element_located` or `visibility_of_element_located`